# aligned creates unwanted white space

Tags: amsmath, aligned

I would like to show [Vandermond polynomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vandermonde_polynomial).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
$$\begin{aligned}
    \Delta=(X_4-X_3)&(X_4-X_2)&(X_4-X_1)\\
                    &(X_3-X_2)&(X_3-X_1)\\
                    &         &(X_2-X1)
\end{aligned}$$
\end{document}
```

However, it inserts unwanted white space.

[image: my output]

How can I resolve this?

Comment: (1) where exactly are yor alignments here? Remember the numbner of `&`'s per row is `2 x <number of alignments> - 1`, so if you have two alignments you need 3 &s on each line. (2) Aligned adds space between alignments, if you do not want that use `alignedat` and remember it takes a mandatory argument.

Comment: You are not supposed to use `$$` in the regular LaTeX, even though markdown editors which implement MathJax promote `$$`. You should use `\[...\]`, instead. See [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/503/why-is-preferable-to) for more info.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`aligned` as well as any other align-like environment creates columns similarly to `tabular` environment. Each column is separated by `&` and each row ends with `\\`. Alignment in columns alternates between right and left starting from the right. Additionally, `align` and `aligned` create small space between every second column or group of pairs.

In your case the last column falls into the very next group, hence the extra space and it is right aligned w.r.t. the other part, so you could expect some tiny extra space as well.

You could use `align` environment without any groups or `&` and right-align the whole thing

```latex
\begin{align*}
    \Delta = (X_4-X_3)(X_4-X_2)(X_4-X_1) \\
                      (X_3-X_2)(X_3-X_1) \\
                               (X_2-X_1)
\end{align*}
```

You could also use `alignat*` or its counterpart `alignedat` to eliminate extra spacing between groups. Then, double `&&` would keep each cell right aligned. Note, `alignat` takes a mandatory argument `n` to specify a number of groups of paired columns. Usually the formulae is `n/2` rounded to the next integer, where `n` denotes a number of columns. Also note the extra `{}` after `=`. This is to let LaTeX add the standard space around an operator

```latex
\begin{alignat*}{4}
    \Delta &={} &(X_4-X_3)&&(X_4-X_2)&&(X_4-X_1) \\
           &    &         &&(X_3-X_2)&&(X_3-X_1) \\
           &    &         &&         &&(X_2-X_1)
\end{alignat*}
```

EDIT. I should have pointed out an issue related to vertical spacing when using `align`-like environments. Please see [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/698278/31283) for the details.

Here's the fill code with both examples

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}


\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
    \Delta = (X_4-X_3)(X_4-X_2)(X_4-X_1) \\
                      (X_3-X_2)(X_3-X_1) \\
                               (X_2-X_1)
\end{align*}

\begin{alignat*}{4}
    \Delta &={} &(X_4-X_3)&&(X_4-X_2)&&(X_4-X_1) \\
           &    &         &&(X_3-X_2)&&(X_3-X_1) \\
           &    &         &&         &&(X_2-X_1)
\end{alignat*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Please have a look at the picture in my answer, which shows that `align*` is not generally the best choice.

Comment: @egreg It's an issue I sometimes forget to mention about. I added a note and link to you answer, so that OP can see the difference. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

With `aligned` you're allowed to have several pairs of right- and left-aligned columns, with space between the pairs.

You can exploit the fact that the parenthesized expressions all have the same width and that the first column in `aligned` is right aligned, so alignment will be automatic

```
\[
\begin{aligned}
  \Delta=(X_4-X_3)(X_4-X_2)(X_4-X_1)\\
                  (X_3-X_2)(X_3-X_1)\\
                           (X_2-X_1)
\end{aligned}
\]
```

but please remember that `$$` is never to be used
in a LaTeX `document` environment. If you know
what you're doing, there are selected situations where
an environment may be defined using `$$`, but this
requires having read the TeXbook at least ten times.

Full example, where I added a comparison with `align*` to show that you should use `aligned` whenever possible.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

You can exploit the fact that the parenthesized expressions
all have the same width and that the first column in
\texttt{aligned} is right aligned, so alignment will be
automatic
\[
\begin{aligned}
  \Delta=(X_4-X_3)(X_4-X_2)(X_4-X_1)\\
                  (X_3-X_2)(X_3-X_1)\\
                           (X_2-X_1)
\end{aligned}
\]
but please remember that \verb|$$| is never to be used
in a \LaTeX\ \texttt{document} environment. If you know
what you're doing, there are selected situations where
an environment may be defined using \verb|$$|, but this
requires having read the \TeX book at least ten times.

You can exploit the fact that the parenthesized expressions
all have the same width and that the first column in
\texttt{align*} is right aligned, so alignment will be
automatic
\begin{align*}
  \Delta=(X_4-X_3)(X_4-X_2)(X_4-X_1)\\
                  (X_3-X_2)(X_3-X_1)\\
                           (X_2-X_1)
\end{align*}
but you can notice a difference with the previous display
in that the vertical spacing is bigger here.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Use `alignedat` for multiple alignment points in case you cannot count on the natural width of the objects. This also creates pairs of right- and left-aligned columns, but adds no space between them.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

You can also use \texttt{alignedat}, but it's really
overkill
\[
\begin{alignedat}{3}
  \Delta=(X_4-X_3)&&(X_4-X_2)&&(X_4-X_1)\\
                  &&(X_3-X_2)&&(X_3-X_1)\\
                  &&         &&(X_2-X_1)
\end{alignedat}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]